# Need a function to sort an array of values in javascript, those values are combination of numbers and alphabets

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Need a sorting function to sort an array of values in javascript, My input array looks like below

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 'N/A', 4,'N/A', 5, 'N/A','N/A'];
```

and my expected output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A"]
```

but it is sorting by the numeric values only by excluding the string values. the output which I'm getting looks like below.

```
[1, 2, 3, 'N/A', 4,'N/A', 5, 'N/A','N/A'];
```

The below is the function which I'm using to sort the array.

```
const sortFunction = (a, b) => {
  if (a === b) {
    return 0;
  }
  return a < b ? -1 : 1;
};
```

Thanks to all I have found the solution.

```
 const sort = (a, b) => {
   if(typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number'){
      return a - b;
   } 
   if(typeof a === 'number'){
     return -1;
   }
   if(typeof b === 'number'){
     return 1;
   }
   return a.localeCompare(b)
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code that you're expecting to return that output?

Comment: Um, just `array.sort()` ?

Comment: @TylerRoper hi have edited my question please check.

Comment: How are you calling it? Can you use the snippet tool to create a reproducible sample of the issue? (It's to the right of the _Image_ button when editing)

Answer (score 1):

Check number or not and sort using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method accordingly.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 'N/A', 4, 'N/A', 5, 'N/A', 'N/A'];


// check value is number or not, if not number then return Infinity(largest num as possible)
const getSortVal = v => isNaN(v) ? Infinity : v;

// check the difference for sorting
array.sort((a, b) => getSortVal(a) - getSortVal(b))

console.log(array)
```

---

If in case there is a chance for other strings and you want to sort them alphabetically as well then use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method for the string comparison.

```js
const array = [1, 'xxx', 2, 3, 'N/A', 4, 'N/A', 5, 'N/A', 'N/A', 'dsds', 'aa', 'zzz'];


// check value is number or not, if not number then return Infinity(largest num as possible)
const getSortVal = v => isNaN(v) ? Infinity : v;


// check both are strings then use localeCompare for string comparison 
// or use number difference as previously
array.sort((a, b) => isNaN(a) && isNaN(b) ? a.localeCompare(b) : getSortVal(a) - getSortVal(b))


console.log(array)
```

Comment: Hi @Pranav actually I'm using this function to sort a DevExpress React Grid, when I'm using this function it's not working. can you help to solve this?

Comment: @Ram :c sure let me check

Comment: @Ram  : can you share your code?

Comment: thanks @PranavCBalan

Comment: [Dev Express](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/sorting/) in this can you check **Custom Sorting Algorithm**

Comment: @Ram : i think you are missing `const getSortVal = v => isNaN(v) ? Infinity : v;`

Comment: @Ram :  can you share error details as well ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191931/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-ram).

Answer (score 1):

As with any "multi-part" problem, the correct solution is to break down the problem.

In this case, you want to sort the numbers first, then sort the strings, and finally join them together.

```
const numbers = array.filter(x=>typeof x === 'number');
const strings = array.filter(x=>typeof x === 'string');

numbers.sort((a,b)=>a-b); // sort numerically
strings.sort(); // sort as strings (optional I guess in your case?)

return [...numbers, ...strings];
```

Comment: That's more complete answer.

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't really do much to explain to OP why his/her attempt doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 'N/A', 4,'N/A', 5, 'N/A','N/A'];

const sortFunction = (a, b) => +a !== a || a - b;

console.log(...array.sort(sortFunction));
```

**How it works:** `+a` converts `a` to a number, so `+a !== a || a - b` returns `true` if `a` is not a number, otherwise it returns the difference between `a` and `b`.

Comment: thanks @p.s.w.g, but here I need to pass this function to Dev Express Grid in that case its failing

Comment: @Ram Sure thing, just pull the function out as its own variable so you can pass the function to your grid by itself.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could first sort by `NaN` or not and then by value.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 'N/A', 4,'N/A', 5, 'N/A','N/A'];

array.sort((a, b) => isNaN(a) - isNaN(b) || a - b);

console.log(array)
```

Comment: thanks @Nina, but here I need to pass this function to Dev Express ReactJs Grid in that case its failing